# Switch button style is disabled

Tags: jquery, button

I have a submit button that I am applying CSS styles (background image, font, etc.).  I need a separate style applied to the button when it is disabled.  What's easiest way to switch styles dynamically whether the button is enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the `:disabled` pseudo class:

```
input:disabled { background-color : lime }
```

More information here: [http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:disabled](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3adisabled)

Answer (score 0):

I think about class, you can assign style to classes and switch them in js as you need (it is more general solution, you can use those class to other elements as well).

```
.classA { .. }
.classB { .. }

$('button').addClass('classA');
$('button').removeClass('classA');
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to support IE6 you an use an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors), for example:

```
button[disabled] {
   // ...
}
```

or

```
#mysubmitbutton[disabled] {
   // ...
}
```